# Convert a where clause in SQL into a regex

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to convert this query to use a regex?

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE series LIKE 'X-1' 
   OR series LIKE 'X-2' 
   OR series LIKE 'X-3'
```

`WHERE` series too repetitive.

Comment: What is your actual SQL engine (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) ?  We need to know this in order to answer the question.

Comment: In the absence of a specific RDBMS tag, I have added one based on @LukStorms' comment.

Comment: @halfer changed the tag to postgresql, since the accepted answer uses `SIMILAR TO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'pipe' inside the regex with the keyword '`SIMILAR TO`' instead of using '`OR`' multiple times

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE series SIMILAR TO '(X-1|X-2|X-3)'
```

Ref: https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/how-regex-works-in-sql/

Comment: no need % and works like a charm. thanks